# Gaps in resource scheduled time

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I'm attempting to use the "Level All" button in MS Project 2013 Professional.  There are three resources, which you can see in the screenshot, with two of the resources working on the same item, shown in gray.  Since both resources are assigned to the same task, why on earth would MS Project leave a gap for one of these resources, effectively keeping him idle, while the task assigned to him is not yet complete?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is the second resource working the same number of hours at the same assignment unit?  Look at the Task Usage view and add "peak" to the left side of the view to see assignment units.

Regarding the gap - my guess is the other task is a successor to the gray task.  The resource leveling command will not ensure the resource is assigned to something every day in the project.  It is merely to solve resource overallocation by delaying tasks.